# How to replace outliers with values inside the IQR for multiple variables and individuals

Tags: r, function, loops, iteration, quartile

I have a dataset similar to `iris`, and need to write a function that deals with outliers in the following way: for each species `setosa`, `versicolor`, and `virginica`, within each variable `iris$Sepal.Length`, `iris$Sepal.Width`, `iris$Petal.Length`, and `Petal.Width`, replace values that fall outside 1.5*IQR with the value of the IQR +/- 1.5*IQR (depending on if it falls above or below the IQR). I have been using the following code to achieve this, but it is very repetitive, time consuming, and error-prone. Also, doing it this way changes the values in the original objects. It would be nice to incorporate arguments into a function that would not only achieve this, but tell me which values were changed and save all the output into a new data frame instead of changing the values in the original dataset.

```r
data(iris)
#create separate objects containing the data for each species 
setosa <-
  iris%>%
  filter(Species == "setosa")

versicolor <- 
  iris%>%
  filter(Species == "versicolor")

virginica <- 
  iris%>%
  filter(Species == "virginica")
#for each variable within each species, do the following:
#create an object (qnt) that contains the 25th and 75th percentile 
#create an object (H) containing the value of 1.5 times the interquartile range(IQR)
#replace any number less than the 25th percentile minus H with the value of the
#25th percentile minus H
#replace any number greater than the 75th percentile plus H with the value of the 
#75th percentile plus H

qnt <- quantile(setosa$Sepal.Length, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
H <- 1.5*IQR(setosa$Sepal.Length, na.rm = T)
setosa$Sepal.Length[setosa$Sepal.Length < (qnt[1] - H)] <- qnt[1]-H
setosa$Sepal.Length[setosa$Sepal.Length > (qnt[2] + H)] <- qnt[2]+H

qnt <- quantile(setosa$Sepal.Width, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
H <- 1.5*IQR(setosa$Sepal.Width, na.rm = T)
setosa$Sepal.Width[setosa$Sepal.Width < (qnt[1] - H)] <- qnt[1]-H
setosa$Sepal.Width[setosa$Sepal.Width > (qnt[2] + H)] <- qnt[2]+H

qnt <- quantile(setosa$Petal.Length, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
H <- 1.5*IQR(setosa$Petal.Length, na.rm = T)
setosa$Petal.Length[setosa$Petal.Length < (qnt[1] - H)] <- qnt[1]-H
setosa$Petal.Length[setosa$Petal.Length > (qnt[2] + H)] <- qnt[2]+H

qnt <- quantile(setosa$Petal.Width, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
H <- 1.5*IQR(setosa$Petal.Width, na.rm = T)
setosa$Sepal.Width[setosa$Petal.Width < (qnt[1] - H)] <- qnt[1]-H
setosa$Sepal.Width[setosa$Petal.Width > (qnt[2] + H)] <- qnt[2]+H

#now do versicolor

qnt <- quantile(versicolor$Sepal.Length, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
H <- 1.5*IQR(versicolor$Sepal.Length, na.rm = T)
versicolor$Sepal.Length[versicolor$Sepal.Length < (qnt[1] - H)] <- qnt[1]-H
versicolor$Sepal.Length[versicolor$Sepal.Length > (qnt[2] + H)] <- qnt[2]+H

qnt <- quantile(versicolor$Sepal.Width, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
H <- 1.5*IQR(versicolor$Sepal.Width, na.rm = T)
versicolor$Sepal.Width[versicolor$Sepal.Width < (qnt[1] - H)] <- qnt[1]-H
versicolor$Sepal.Width[versicolor$Sepal.Width > (qnt[2] + H)] <- qnt[2]+H

qnt <- quantile(versicolor$Petal.Length, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
H <- 1.5*IQR(versicolor$Petal.Length, na.rm = T)
versicolor$Petal.Length[versicolor$Petal.Length < (qnt[1] - H)] <- qnt[1]-H
versicolor$Petal.Length[versicolor$Petal.Length > (qnt[2] + H)] <- qnt[2]+H

qnt <- quantile(versicolor$Petal.Width, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
H <- 1.5*IQR(versicolor$Petal.Width, na.rm = T)
versicolor$Sepal.Width[versicolor$Petal.Width < (qnt[1] - H)] <- qnt[1]-H
versicolor$Sepal.Width[versicolor$Petal.Width > (qnt[2] + H)] <- qnt[2]+H

#now do virginica

qnt <- quantile(virginica$Sepal.Length, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
H <- 1.5*IQR(virginica$Sepal.Length, na.rm = T)
virginica$Sepal.Length[virginica$Sepal.Length < (qnt[1] - H)] <- qnt[1]-H
virginica$Sepal.Length[virginica$Sepal.Length > (qnt[2] + H)] <- qnt[2]+H

qnt <- quantile(virginica$Sepal.Width, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
H <- 1.5*IQR(virginica$Sepal.Width, na.rm = T)
virginica$Sepal.Width[virginica$Sepal.Width < (qnt[1] - H)] <- qnt[1]-H
virginica$Sepal.Width[virginica$Sepal.Width > (qnt[2] + H)] <- qnt[2]+H

qnt <- quantile(virginica$Petal.Length, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
H <- 1.5*IQR(virginica$Petal.Length, na.rm = T)
virginica$Petal.Length[virginica$Petal.Length < (qnt[1] - H)] <- qnt[1]-H
virginica$Petal.Length[virginica$Petal.Length > (qnt[2] + H)] <- qnt[2]+H

qnt <- quantile(virginica$Petal.Width, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
H <- 1.5*IQR(virginica$Petal.Width, na.rm = T)
virginica$Sepal.Width[virginica$Petal.Width < (qnt[1] - H)] <- qnt[1]-H
virginica$Sepal.Width[virginica$Petal.Width > (qnt[2] + H)] <- qnt[2]+H
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to create a function and then apply over the columns after grouping by 'Species', and assign it to a new object.  With `dplyr`, the original datasets are not changed on the fly unless we use special operators from `magrittr` (`%<>%` instead of `%>%`)

```
f1 <- function(x) {
       qnt <- quantile(x, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = TRUE)
       H <- 1.5*IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE)
       x[x< (qnt[1] - H)] <- qnt[1]-H
       x[x> (qnt[2] + H)] <- qnt[2]+H
       x
       }

library(dplyr)
iris1 <- iris %>% 
             group_by(Species) %>%
             mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), f1)
```

Also, in case we need to apply only the numeric columns (if the dataset have other columns with different types)

```
iris1 <- iris %>%
            group_by(Species) %>%
            mutate_if(is.numeric, f1)
```